# What is the difference between the delimiter $$ and ' used in pl/pgsql after the create function returns as statement?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

The statement:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123(fstname text) RETURNS text AS $$`
and
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123(fstname text) RETURNS text AS '`

returns the same values when the argument is passed. Then what is the difference between the two statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in that both are acceptable forms of quoting. The benefit of using dollar-quotes is that you would not need to escape any inside single-quotes.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING